# Stop httputils service in basic4android

Tags: service, basic4android

I am using basic4android and I made an application that uses httputils services. Sometimes a remote error occurs (possible server overload or limited internet connection) and the application exits with the error message box. The activity closes but httputils service is still running. While I reopen the activity new error occurs, because of the unfinished job of httputils. Everything is OK only if I choose to stop the activity in the second error.
Is there any way to determine if the httputils service is running by a previous instance of my app? Or better, a way to try to stop this service either its running or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpUtils errors should not cause your program to exit. You should check IsSuccess to make sure that the call succeeded or not.

You can stop the service from running by calling StopService(HttpUtilsService).

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub StationTransfer_Click

    Dim job As HttpJob
    job.Initialize("MyJob", Me)

    Dim URL As String="https://www.yourserver.com/myjob.asmx/GetData?parameter1=abc"

    job.Download(URL)

    ProgressDialogShow2("Getting data From Server...", True)

End Sub

Sub JobDone(Job As HttpJob)
    Select Job.JobName
        Case "MyJob"
            HandleMyJob(Job)

    End Select
    Job.Release

End Sub
Sub HandleMyJob(Job As HttpJob)

    If Job.Success = False Then
        ToastMessageShow("Error downloading Data", True)
        ProgressDialogHide
        Return
    End If

   ....
end Sub
```

if there is an httpjob error you catch it in the handler function by looking at the status.  if the status is not success than you catch it and display a message.